# Autoresizing UIImageView in a TableView Cell with Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I am trying to get a UIImageView to change its height dynamically according to the picture that it is given. The UIImageView its inside a custom cell.

Here are the constraints:

1. Must span from the edge of the screen to the other edge.
2. Its height must be dynamic and not surpass the frame's width.

So far I've added the following constraints to the UIImageView using the Interface Builder:

[image]

I use the height constraint in code (referred as `postHeight`)to change the height of the UIImageView as shown below:

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var post:UIImage! = nil {
        didSet {
            let x = post.size.width
            let y = post.size.height
            var newHeight = (y / x) * self.frame.width
            newHeight = newHeight > self.frame.width ? self.frame.width : newHeight
            postHeight.constant = newHeight
            postImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            postImage.image = post
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

When running, the console shows that it was unable to satisfy some constraints. And outputs:

```
TryImageView[89952:2477907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef8560 V:[UIImageView:0x7aef96b0(291.355)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef9b30 UIImageView:0x7aef96b0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7aef9340.topMargin - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef9b90 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7aef9340.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7aef96b0.bottom - 8.5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae5e990 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7aef9340(291)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef8560 V:[UIImageView:0x7aef96b0(291.355)]>
```

The table view has this in its viewDidLoad() since the cells need to resize as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Any ideas as to why my constraints are not working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are setting constraints for your image view as:

- Connected to top, left, right, and bottom
- Fixed Height

Remove the height constraint. Say the height of your cell is 50. You cannot fix the height of your image view. If it covers the entire cell, its height will be 50 as well. You need to find out your images' heights, and put them in an array.

```
var heights = [CGFloat]()
```

When you find your heights:

```
heights = [50, 60, 70]
```

Then in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, return these heights.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return heights[indexPath.row]
}
```

You also should set the `contentMode` of your image view.

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```